# Can clang-format put spaces inside JavaScript object literals’ braces?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, clang-format

In JavaScript code like `{ foo: bar }`, is there any way to make clang-format preserve the spaces just inside the braces?

I’ve studied the [clang-format docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) pretty carefully and the closest is `SpacesInContainerLiterals`, but that’ll only put spaces inside brackets, like `[ 1, 2 ]` (also my requirement) but removes spaces inside braces. (That config also adds spaces around colons inside braces, which I can’t have).

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed Fasih is only partially correct. This option (`Cpp11BracedListStyle: false`) does not seem to work 100% of the time for import statements.

```
// input
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

```
// output
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Aha, you're right! So sad! This is something TSLint/ESLint etc. support extensive customization of, but I guess that doesn't mean clang-format would necessarily have parity there…

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Cpp11BracedListStyle: false` will work even on JavaScript files!